# error- An alias was previously found. (near "Ranking" at position 61)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, error-handling, phpmyadmin

code-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `id` int(250) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ram',
  `score` int(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=161 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `scores`
--

INSERT INTO `scores` (`id`, `name`, `score`) VALUES
(1, 'ram', 200),
(2, 'ram', 200),
(3, 'ram', 200),
(4, 'ram', 80),
(5, 'ram', 55),
(6, 'ram', 40),
(7, 'ram', 30),
(8, 'ramu', 80),
(9, 'ram', 70),
(10, 'ram', 45),
(11, 'ram', 40),
(12, 'ram', 30),
(13, 'ram', 65),
(14, 'ram', 70),
(15, 'ram', 45),
(16, 'ram', 55),
(17, 'ram', 45),
(18, 'ram', 83),
(19, 'ram', 85),
(20, 'ram', 60),
(21, 'ram', 50),
(22, 'ram', 40),
(23, 'ram', 75),
(24, 'ram', 80),
(25, 'ram', 55),
(26, 'ram', 40),
(27, 'ram', 30),
(28, 'ram', 80),
(29, 'ram', 70),
(30, 'ram', 45),
(31, 'ram', 40),
(32, 'ram', 30),
(33, 'ram', 65),
(34, 'ram', 70),
(35, 'ram', 45),
(36, 'ram', 55),
(37, 'ram', 45),
(38, 'ram', 83),
(39, 'ram', 85),
(40, 'ram', 60),
(41, 'ram', 50),
(42, 'ram', 40),
(43, 'ram', 75),
(44, 'ram', 80),
(45, 'ram', 55),
(46, 'ram', 40),
(47, 'ram', 30),
(48, 'ram', 80),
(49, 'ram', 70),
(50, 'ram', 45),
(51, 'ram', 40),
(52, 'ram', 30),
(53, 'ram', 65),
(54, 'ram', 70),
(55, 'ram', 45),
(56, 'ram', 55),
(57, 'ram', 45),
(58, 'ram', 83),
(59, 'ram', 85),
(60, 'ram', 60),
(61, 'ram', 50),
(62, 'ram', 40),
(63, 'ram', 75),
(64, 'ram', 80),
(65, 'ram', 55),
(66, 'ram', 40),
(67, 'ram', 30),
(68, 'ram', 80),
(69, 'ram', 70),
(70, 'ram', 45),
(71, 'ram', 40),
(72, 'ram', 30),
(73, 'ram', 65),
(74, 'ram', 70),
(75, 'ram', 45),
(76, 'ram', 55),
(77, 'ram', 45),
(78, 'ram', 83),
(79, 'ram', 85),
(80, 'ram', 60),
(81, 'ram', 50),
(82, 'ram', 40),
(83, 'ram', 75),
(84, 'ram', 80),
(85, 'ram', 55),
(86, 'ram', 40),
(87, 'ram', 30),
(88, 'ram', 80),
(89, 'ram', 70),
(90, 'ram', 45),
(91, 'ram', 40),
(92, 'ram', 30),
(93, 'ram', 65),
(94, 'ram', 70),
(95, 'ram', 45),
(96, 'ram', 55),
(97, 'ram', 45),
(98, 'ram', 83),
(99, 'ram', 85),
(100, 'ram', 60),
(101, 'ram', 50),
(102, 'ram', 40),
(103, 'ram', 75),
(104, 'ram', 80),
(105, 'ram', 55),
(106, 'ram', 40),
(107, 'ram', 30),
(108, 'ram', 80),
(109, 'ram', 70),
(110, 'ram', 45),
(111, 'ram', 40),
(112, 'ram', 30),
(113, 'ram', 65),
(114, 'ram', 70),
(115, 'ram', 45),
(116, 'ram', 55),
(117, 'ram', 45),
(118, 'ram', 83),
(119, 'ram', 85),
(120, 'ram', 60),
(121, 'ram', 50),
(122, 'ram', 40),
(123, 'ram', 75),
(124, 'ram', 80),
(125, 'ram', 55),
(126, 'ram', 40),
(127, 'ram', 30),
(128, 'ram', 80),
(129, 'ram', 70),
(130, 'ram', 45),
(131, 'ram', 40),
(132, 'ram', 30),
(133, 'ram', 65),
(134, 'ram', 70),
(135, 'ram', 45),
(136, 'ram', 55),
(137, 'ram', 45),
(138, 'ram', 83),
(139, 'ram', 85),
(140, 'ram', 60),
(141, 'ram', 50),
(142, 'ram', 40),
(143, 'ram', 75),
(144, 'ram', 80),
(145, 'ram', 55),
(146, 'ram', 40),
(147, 'ram', 30),
(148, 'ram', 80),
(149, 'ram', 70),
(150, 'ram', 45),
(151, 'ram', 40),
(152, 'ram', 30),
(153, 'ram', 65),
(154, 'ram', 70),
(155, 'ram', 45),
(156, 'ram', 55),
(157, 'ram', 45),
(158, 'ram', 83),
(159, 'ram', 85),
(160, 'ram', 60);

select *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) AS `ranking` from scores;
```

Note-

1. running flawlessly in https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=mysql
2. not able to run on phpmyadmin

request assistant from you people.
Thank you

Comment: "Not able" means what? Do you get an error?

Comment: `ENGINE=MyISAM` is somewhat concerning. Databases should be `InnoDB` by default. MyISAM is woefully inadequate by modern standards. Likewise `int(250)` is really bizarre, `INT` can't possibly hold 250 places so that's just silly.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Window functions require 8.x.

Comment: Were it to exist, Int(250) would be capable of storing a number substantially larger than the number of atoms in the known universe

Comment: And if the engine is MyISAM then the bundled MySQL version is likely to be ancient

Comment: "Not Able" means when i am running the sql query on localhost server i am getting attached error image, Sir

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2fNK.png

Comment: sql version is 5.7.23